# Simple script is just not working when requesting the data - the calculations arent correct

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Hi I am trying to get the below script to work. It looks to be really simple however I cant seem to get it to work properly. I know the calculation could be done easier with the SMA function however dont want it to include the current bar.

plot(data, color=color.new(color.orange, 0), style=plot.style_circles) //This works as it should when on the ticker and daily  timeframe however dosent pull the daily data through when on the 5 minute.

plot(request.security('AAPL','D',data))// as a result I have tried to plot it like this in order to get it to pull through however the result is different even when on the daily timeframe.

I just dont understand how they can be different.
I will also want to add QQQ and Spy to this also so that I can always keep an eye on these also however I know if this issue is fixed its just a case of repeating the code with amendments

```
indicator(title='AAPL', overlay=true, precision=1)

data = (volume/((volume[1]+volume[2]+volume[3]+volume[4]+volume[5]+volume[6]+volume[7]+volume[8]+volume[9]+volume[10])/10))*100

plot(data, color=color.new(color.orange, 0), style=plot.style_circles) 

plot(request.security('AAPL','D',data))
```

Comment: Why would `plot(data, color=color.new(color.orange, 0), style=plot.style_circles)` pull data from the daily timeframe when you are on the 5 min timeframe? There is no `security()` call there.

Comment: "I know the calculation could be done easier with the SMA function however dont want it to include the current bar" then you can use `sma[1]`.

Comment: HI thanks for the SMA help,. Is this not a security request for it? plot(request.security('AAPL','D',data)   is this my issue? @vitruvius

Comment: It is. I thought you were expecting the first plot function to pull data from the daily timeframe.

Comment: no sorry. I should have probably worded it better. but for some reason when using the Security() plot it isnt calculating correctly and I cant figure out why. I have plotted just volume within that call  to try and determine why and it is calculating a different number to the actual volume, which the first plot is doing correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer (so obvious as always when you know) the ticker ID didn't have the broker as well this is why it didn't match up to my chart